# Select column which have same name from subquery

Tags: mysql

Two tables have the same name Id, now I want to get both id columns from subquery by using where clause on subquery

Here is the query having two columns p.id and s.id

```
select name,price,total,user_id,id,id from(
SELECT p.name,p.price,s.user_id,s.id,p.id FROM products p,shoping_cart 
s where p.id=s.product_id
) z where z.user_id=11
```

Comment: Use an alias, e.g. ‘s.id as sid’, then you basically renamed the column and you can use the alias in the outer query.

Comment: Hi, give alias names to your columns in the subquery, like this: `select ...,id_s,id_p from ( select .., s.id as ID_S, p.id as ID_P from ..) ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can try to use alias name to represent those two columns.

There is no reason need to use subquery in your query, you can try to `select` it directly.

I would use `join` syntax instead of `,` comma to connect two tables, because `,` mean `CROSS JOIN` it is an old style.

```
SELECT 
    p.name,
    p.price,
    s.user_id,
    s.id 'sid',
    p.id 'pid'
FROM products p JOIN shoping_cart s  on p.id=s.product_id
WHERE s.user_id = 11
```